# How to read a file in other directory in python

Tags: python

I have a file named  `5_1.txt` in a directory named `direct`, how can I read that file using `read`?

I verified the path using :

```
import os
os.getcwd()
os.path.exists(direct)
```

the result was
True

```
x_file=open(direct,'r')
```

and I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
x_file=open(direct,'r')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I don't know why I can't read the file ? Any suggestions?

thanks .

Comment: Perhaps the user you are running Python as does not have permissions to open the file. Run Python as a different user or change the owner/group of the file.

Comment: Could you run ls -l on the file your are trying to access? You will probably see that you do not have read permission on the file (assuming Unix)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to open a *directory* for reading as if it's a regular file. Many OSs won't let you do that. You don't need to anyway, because what you want (judging from your description) is

```
x_file = open(os.path.join(direct, "5_1.txt"), "r")
```

or simply

```
x_file = open(direct+"/5_1.txt", "r")
```

Answer (score 11):

In case you're not in the specified directory (i.e. direct), you should use (in linux):

```
x_file = open('path/to/direct/filename.txt')
```

Note the quotes and the relative path to the directory.

This may be your problem, but you also don't have permission to access that file.
Maybe you're trying to open it as another user.

Comment: i have windows xp , but i don't know what is "another user", and if this is the case , so how can overcome this issue ?

Comment: The file might also already be in use. Some other app might have opened it and not closed it.

Answer (score 5):

You can't "open" a *directory* using the `open` function. This function is meant to be used to open *files*.

Here, what you want to do is open the *file* that's in the *directory*. The first thing you must do is compute this file's path. The `os.path.join` function will let you do that by joining parts of the path (the directory and the file name):

```
fpath = os.path.join(direct, "5_1.txt")
```

You can then open the file:

```
f = open(fpath)
```

And read its content:

```
content = f.read()
```

---

Additionally, I believe that on Windows, using `open` on a directory does return a `PermissionDenied` exception, although that's not really the case.

Answer (score 2):

i found this way useful also.

```
import tkinter.filedialog
from_filename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

here a window will appear so you can browse till you find the file , you click on it then you can continue using open , and read .

```
from_file = open(from_filename, 'r')
contents = from_file.read()
contents
```

Answer (score 1):

For folks like me looking at the accepted answer, and not understanding why it's not working, you need to add quotes around your sub directory, in the green checked example,

```
x_file = open(os.path.join(direct, "5_1.txt"), "r")
```

should actually be

```
x_file = open(os.path.join('direct', "5_1.txt"), "r")
```

Answer (score 1):

**For windows** you can either use the full path with '\\' ('/' **for Linux and Mac**) as separator of you can use os.getcwd to get the current working directory and give path in reference to the current working directory

```
data_dir = os.getcwd()+'\\child_directory'
file = open(data_dir+'\\filename.txt', 'r')
```

When I tried to give the path of child_diectory entirely it resulted in error. For e.g. in this case:

```
file = open('child_directory\\filename.txt', 'r')
```

Resulted in error. But I think it must work or I am doing it somewhat wrong way but it doesn't work for me. The about way always works.

Answer (score 0):

As error message said your application has no permissions to read from the directory. It can be the case when you created the directory as one user and run script as another user.