# Copying files raises a SyntaxError can't decode bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to code a short program that makes backups of a folder whenever I run it. Currently it's like this:

```
import time
import shutil
import os

date = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
print(date)

shutil.copy2("C:\Users\joaop\Desktop\VanillaServer\world","C:\Users\joaop\Desktop\VanillaServer\Backups")

for filename in os.listdir("C:\Users\joaop\Desktop\VanillaServer\Backups"):
    if filename == world:
        os.rename(filename, "Backup " + date)
```

However I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

and I can't figure out why (according to documentation, I think my code is properly written)

How can I fix this/do it in a better way?

Comment: You should probably escape the backslashes or use raw strings: `"C:\\Users..."` or `r"C:\Users..."`

Comment: ... or use forward slashes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes are used for escape characters so when the interpreter sees the `\` in your file path string it attempts to use them as an escape character (which are things like `\n` for new line and `\t` for tabs).

There are 2 ways around this, using raw strings or double slashing your file path so the interpeter ignores the escape sequence. Use a `r` to specify a raw string or `\\`. Now the choice in which you use is up to you but personally I prefer raw strings.

```
#with raw strings
shutil.copy2(r"C:\Users\joaop\Desktop\VanillaServer\world",r"C:\Users\joaop\Desktop\VanillaServer\Backups")

for filename in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\joaop\Desktop\VanillaServer\Backups"):
    if filename == world:
        os.rename(filename, "Backup " + date)

#with double slashes
shutil.copy2("C:\\Users\\joaop\\Desktop\\VanillaServer\\world","C:\\Users\\joaop\\Desktop\\VanillaServer\\Backups")

for filename in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\joaop\\Desktop\\VanillaServer\\Backups"):
    if filename == world:
        os.rename(filename, "Backup " + date)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python, `\u...` denotes a Unicode sequence, so your `\Users` directory is interpreted as a Unicode character -- not with very much success.

```
>>> "\u0061"
'a'
>>> "\users"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

To fix it, you should escape the different `\` as `\\`, or use `r"..."` to make it a raw string.

```
>>> "C:\\Users\\joaop\\Desktop\\VanillaServer\\world"
'C:\\Users\\joaop\\Desktop\\VanillaServer\\world'
>>> r"C:\Users\joaop\Desktop\VanillaServer\world"
'C:\\Users\\joaop\\Desktop\\VanillaServer\\world'
```

Don't do both, though, or else they will be escaped twice:

```
>>> r"C:\\Users\\joaop\\Desktop\\VanillaServer\\world"
'C:\\\\Users\\\\joaop\\\\Desktop\\\\VanillaServer\\\\world'
```

You only have to escape them when entering the paths directly in your source; if you read those paths from a file, from user input, or from some library function, they will automatically be escaped.