# pandas-read_excel syntax error

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to read in some data from the second sheet of a excel spreadsheet. skipping the first 18 rows and only columns C to F. This is what I have tried

```
import pandas as pd

new_file=pd.read_excel("C:\Users\denis\Documents\Dissertation\Raw Data\CO\1213Q1.xls",sheetname=1, skiprows=18, parse_cols=[2,5])
```

when I run this I get the following error

```
runfile('C:/Users/denis/Documents/Dissertation/Code/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/denis/Documents/Dissertation/Code')
  File "C:/Users/denis/Documents/Dissertation/Code/test.py", line 9
    new_file=pd.read_excel("C:\Users\denis\Documents\Dissertation\Raw Data\CO\1213Q1.xls",sheetname=1, skiprows=18, parse_cols=[2,5])
                          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46011113/9609447) solve your problem? May be you need to add `r` before filename. `pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\denis\Documents\Dissertation\Raw Data\CO\1213Q1.xls",..)`

Comment: its the simple things. thank you

Answer (score 4):

You either have to escape the backslashes or use `r` in front to indicate raw string, i.e.

```
new_file=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\denis\Documents\Dissertation\Raw Data\CO\1213Q1.xls",sheetname=1, skiprows=18, parse_cols=[2,5]))
```

or

```
new_file=pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\denis\\Documents\\Dissertation\\Raw Data\\CO\\1213Q1.xls",sheetname=1, skiprows=18, parse_cols=[2,5]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question: ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

I suggest not passing a `str` as the first argument, and instead letting `pathlib.Path` handle this for you. Also, the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) specify `sheetname` and `parse_cols` are deprecated and `skiprows` should be list-like.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

p = Path('C:\Users\denis\Documents\Dissertation\Raw Data\CO\1213Q1.xls')
df = pd.read_excel(
    p, 
    sheet_name=1, 
    skiprows=list(range(18)), # skip first 18 rows (0-indexed)
    parse_cols=list(range(2, 6)) # only parse columns 2 (C) to 5 (F)
)
```