# How Can I Plot a TensorBoard Diagram?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I have some diagrams using TensorBoard, and I want to plot them and then save them as images. How can I do this? Is it possible?

I tried:

```
data = np.genfromtxt("C:\Users\maedeh\Downloads\val_model_31_mean_absolute_error.csv",
                 delimiter=',', skip_header=10,
                 skip_footer=10, names=['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

but it produced this error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Can you please help?

Comment: By default np.genfromtxt uses dtype=float. You can ask np.genfromtxt to try to guess the actual type of your columns by using dtype=None. Can you share some of the data inside your .csv file.

Comment: Please print a few lines of your `.csv` file. Is this .csv file, generated by download link in tensorboard GUI?

Comment: yes, I print some of the lines here.            
 Wall time Step Value
1538599140 0 0.27923739
1538599153 1 0.247721538
1538599166 2 0.242293626
1538599178 3 0.23922807

Comment: For this `SyntaxError`, Can you try escaping the backslashes in the file path, You can refer to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37402939/11530462) for more details on the same. Thanks!