# How can I create a text file, name it, and fill it with content?

Tags: text

I have a text file with a list of words with definitions, like this...

```
的   of / ~'s (possessive particle) / (used after an attribute) / (used to form a nominal expression) / (used at the end of a declarative sentence for emphasis)
我   I / me / my
你   you (informal, as opposed to courteous 您[nín])
是   is / are / am / yes / to be / variant of 是[shì] / (used in given names)
了   (modal particle intensifying preceding clause) / (completed action marker)
不   (negative prefix) / not / no
```

I need to create a text file in Windows 10 for each Chinese word in the list with the content of the file being the English definition.

For example I need a text file named `的.txt` ...

...with this content in the file:

```
of / ~'s (possessive particle) / (used after an attribute) / (used to form a nominal expression) / (used at the end of a declarative sentence for emphasis)
```

I'm fairly proficient with Javascript, familiar with python, and have powershell available on my computer.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This is pretty straight forward (as long as some constraints hold true). Do you know how to iterate over the lines of a file, split strings, and create files?

Comment: Also, please decide on one programming language the solution should be in and remove the other tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can just look through each line and split it at triple spaces:

powershell

```
$Content = Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\Temp.txt
foreach ( $Line in $Content )
{
    $Temp = $Line -split '   ' | Where-Object -FilterScript { -not [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) }
    New-Item -Path "C:\Temp" -Name "$($Temp[0]).txt" -Value $Temp[1]
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I got an error probably having to do with the fact that it is Chinese. 
New-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Nathan Cain\Downloads\sample\çš„.txt'.
At line:5 char:5
+     New-Item -Path "C:\Users\Nathan Cain\Downloads\sample\" -Name "$( ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\Nathan...\sample\çš„.txt:String) [New-Item], DirectoryNotFoundExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

Comment: Updated my script because I never ran it. It was supposed to have triple spaces... whoops. Also added handling for whitespace.

Comment: @webmagnets I cannot replicate your issue. I am using PS 5.1 on Windows 10 and don't have that problem creating the files.

Comment: That worked somewhat, but I'm getting wonky file names...

   Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
   ----                -------------         ------ ----
   -a----       10/16/2018  11:46 AM            155 çš„.txt
   -a----       10/16/2018  11:46 AM             11 æˆ‘.txt
   -a----       10/16/2018  11:46 AM             55 ä½ .txt

Comment: @webmagnets must be something with unicode characters. Try replacing `New-Item -Path "C:\Temp" -Name "$($Temp[0]).txt" -Value $Temp[1]` with `$Temp[1] | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\$($Temp[0]).txt" -Encoding unicode -Force`. It's just a different way to write a file.

Comment: I got some files, but the filenames aren't encoded properly. Here is an example: ä»€ä¹ˆ.txt

Comment: @webmagnets Yeah. I understand. However, I am unsure why you are not able to save a file using a Chinese character in the name. It is supported by unicode and filenames support unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this should do the trick.

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as definitions:
    for line in definitions:
        name, definition = line.split(maxsplit=1)
        with open(name + '.txt', 'w') as out:
            out.write(definition)
```

It iterates over the content of the definitions-file line by line, splits each line into the filename and definition part, and then writes the definition into a file with the appropriate name.

Comment: Is this python?

Comment: @webmagnets yes

Comment: I tried your code and got the following...
>>> with open('C:\Users\Nathan Cain\Downloads\sample.txt') as definitions:
...     for line in definitions:
...         name, definition = line.split(maxsplit=1)
...         with open(name + '.txt', 'w') as out:
...             out.write(definition)
...
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
>>>

Is there something special that needs to be done to read the Chinese?

Comment: @webmagnets does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca) help?

Comment: It helped somewhat. Now I got...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Nathan Cain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 405: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @webmagnets does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character) help?

Answer (score 0):

to read

```
with open ("File_name","r") as f:
    f.read()
```

to write

```
with open ('file_name','w') as f:
    f.write('content')
```

Comment: This answer should mention that it's written in Python.