# Problems on training a neural network

Tags: python, algorithm, csv, neural-network, training-data

Good afternoon.

I'm having some problems on opening my database (csv file) and read this on my algorithm test.

Someone could help me on this? Here is my algorithm:

[algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbNTX.png)

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 2):

That should work:

```
pandas.read_csv ("C:\\Users\\DESICHRIS\\Desktop\\ATUAL TESE DESIREE\\em andamento\\entrada pyhton\\entrada.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

by adding `encoding = "ISO-8859-1"` will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for answer me!

Comment: What are the errors? Can you tell me what's going on?

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa7 in position 25: invalid start byte

Comment: pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 12

Comment: I'm trying to open a .csv table with 17 columns of variables. 500 rows, including each column title.

Comment: pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 12

Comment: it looks very simple, what is exactly data in line 3?

Comment: I got it!!!!! I saved my table again and it works!!!! Thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: Since this is a raw string literal (`r` character before the opening `"`), you probably don't need to double up all those backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error occurs because you are using a normal string as a path.
Furthermore there are already other post which cover this topic. For example: [(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca)

Try this: With / and not \

```
import pandas as pd

path = 'C:/Users/Marti/Desktop/Admission_Predict.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(path,encoding= 'utf-8')

print(df)
```

Comment: >>> read_csv ("C:\Users\DESICHRIS\Desktop\ATUAL TESE DESIREE\em andamento\entrada pyhton\entrada.csv")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape