# How to load CSV file in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm new and studying machine learning. I stumble upon a tutorial I found online and I'd like to make the program work so I'll get a better understanding. However, I'm getting problems about loading the CSV File into the Jupyter Notebook.

I get this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-2-70e07fb5b537>", line 2
    student_data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\student-intervention- 
system\student-data.csv")
                          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in 
position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

and here is the code: 
[image]

I followed tutorials online regarding this error but none worked. Does anyone know how to fix it?

3rd attempt with r"path"
[image]

I've tried also "\" and utf-8 but none worked.

I'm using the latest version of Anaconda
Windows 7
Python 3.7

Comment: Put an r before your string or change to \\. \ is an escape character!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca)

Comment: In your 3rd attempt, note that the error has changed.  The file path string itself is OK, but now Jupyter can't find the file you named.  Can *you* see the CSV file on your Windows desktop?  There should be an icon there.  Double check the spelling of the full file path, etc.

Answer (score 14):

Use raw string notation for your Windows path. In python '\' have meaning in python. Try instead do string like this r"path":

`student_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\student-intervention- 
system\student-data.csv")`

If it doesnt work try this way:

```
import os

path = os.path.join('c:' + os.sep, 'Users', 'xxxx', 'Desktop', 'student-intervention-system', 'student-data.csv')
student_data = pd.read_csv(path)
```

Comment: Hi. Tried it. I got an error SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Answer (score 4):

> ### Either replace all backslashes `\` with frontslashes `/` or place a `r` before your filepath string to avoid this error. *It is not a matter of your folder name being too long.*

---

As Bohun Mielecki mentioned, the `\` character which is typically used to denote file structure in Windows has a different function when written within a string.

> **From Python3 Documentation:** The backslash `\` character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

How this particularly affects your statement is that in the line

```
student_data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\student-intervention- 
system\student-data.csv")
```

`\Users` matches the escape sequence `\Uxxxxxxxx` whereby `xxxxxxxx` refers to a `Character with 32-bit hex value xxxxxxxx`. Because of this, Python tries to find a 32-bit hex value. However as the `-sers` from `Users` doesn't match the `xxxxxxxx` format, you get the error:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in 
>   position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

---

The reason why your code works now is that you have placed a `r` in front of `'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\project\student-data.csv'`. This tells python not to process the backslash character `/` as it usually does and read the whole string as-is.

I hope this helps you better understand your problem. If you need any more clarification, do let me know.

Source: [Python 3 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I tried to encode it with 'Latin-1' and it worked for me.

```
    autos = pd.read_csv('filename',encoding = "Latin-1")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing \ to /: -

```
import pandas as pd
student_data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/student-intervention- 
system/student-data.csv")
print(student data)
```

OR

```
import pandas as pd

student_data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/student-intervention- system/student-data.csv"r)

print(student data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `student_data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/student-intervention- 
system/student-data.csv")`.

Replacing backslashes in that code it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a file name with a backlash... try to write the path using two backlashes instead of one.

```
student_data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\student-intervention-system\\student-data.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally this kind of error arises if there is any space in file path...
df=pd.read_csv('/home/jovyan/binder/kidney disease.csv')
above command will create an error and will get resolved when it is
df=pd.read_csv('/home/jovyan/binder/kidney_disease.csv')
replaced space with underscore

Comment: This kind of makes sense considering the question-asker's answer to her own problem. Did you see this error in her original code?

Comment: Taking up the former remark about the [question-asker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55210255/11154841), there *is* a space in the filepath, check the space after `ìnvention- ` at `"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\student-intervention- 
system\student-data.csv")`, and this can also be seen in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68333413/11154841). Therefore, this should be the accepted answer even if the other answers try to make good sense of it and are also helpful for the average searcher. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pd.read_csv('file_name',encoding = "utf-8")
```

Comment: Can you share the updated code and the error? Can you share 'student-data.csv' or a subset of it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The problem is my folder name that is really long. I changed my folder name into "project" and the data is now finally loaded! Silly!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please open notepad, write csv format data into the file and opt 'Save As' to save the file with format `.csv`.
E.g. Train.csv

Use this file, ensure you mention the same path correctly for the above saved CSV file during python coding.

```py
Import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('C:/your_path/Train.csv')
```

I've seen people using existing .txt/other format files to covert their format to .csv by just renaming. Which actually does nothing than changing the name of the file. It doesn't become a CSV file at all.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, this has *nothing* to do with Jupyter. This is a pure Python problem!

In Python, as in most languages, a backslash is an special (escape) character in strings, for example `"foo\"bar"` is the string `foo"bar` without causing a syntax error. Also, `"foo\nbar"` is the strings `foo` and `bar` with a newline in between. There are many more escapes.

In your case, the meaning of `\` in your path is literal, i.e. you actually want a backslash appearing in the string.

One option is to escape the backslash itself with another backslash: `"foo\\bar"` amounts to the string `foo\bar`. However, in your case, you have several of these, so for readability you might want to switch on "raw string mode", which disables (almost all) escapes:

```
r"foo\bar\baz\quux\etc"
```

will produce

```
foo\bar\baz\quuz\etc
```

As a matter of programming style, though, if you want your code to be portable, it is better to use `os.path.join` which knows the right path separator for your OS/platform:

```
In [1]: import os.path

In [2]: os.path.join("foo", "bar", "baz")
Out[2]: 'foo/bar/baz'
```

on Windows, that would produce `foo\bar\baz`.

Answer (score -1):

import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("C:\Users\ss\Desktop\file or csv file name.csv")
just place the csv file on the desktop

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be really useful if you could expand your answer to include more information.  Your answer risks being downvoted if it does not provide supporting details.