# Why doesn't tkinter show me images?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

Each time I try to load an image onto my tkinter app, it refuses to load, rather it springs different errors.

I have used so many different versions of the code. Below is the latest, which still dosen't work but throws an error.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk # I have added the import of ImageTk
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Join")
window.geometry("300x300")
window.configure(background='grey')
imageFile = '\User\PycharmProjects\BRIGHTBROWN\PyShop\tkinter\studentsRecord\myface.jpg'
im1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imageFile))
panel = tkinter.Label(window, image = im1)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

window.mainloop()
```

The error thrown is:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the path.
Make your you provide the **complete path** `"C:\...\User\..."`. After that, there are several ways you can fix it:

**Method #1:**
Replace the backward slash with the forward one. For example:
`"C:/.../User/..."`

**Method #2:**
Use `r` behind the string. For example: `r"C:\...\User\..."`

**Method #3:**
Use Double Backward slashes. For example: `"C:\\...\\User\\..."`