# Python selenium checkbox element click

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

**Context:** I'm writing a Python script to ultimately download postings on the following site (https://ngc.taleo.net/careersection/ngc_pro/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en&_ga=2.59113261.1016801192.1577482911-1938918126.1574124672). I've been able to programmatically navigate the page to search for a keyword, click the search button and drop down a filter field for location.

**Questions:** I've been unable to write the logic to find the california checkbox under the location element. Can someone take a look at the page source snippet below and help me find the correct logic to click on the corresponding california location checkbox element?

Here's a snippet of the page source surrounding the checkbox:

```
<div id="fieldSetId-LOCATION-level-2" class="hidden-audible">State / Province</div><div id="LOCATION-level-2" class="filter-level-title">State / Province</div><input id="LOCATION-level-2-item-0" type="checkbox" name="2160420105" title="California" class="filter-checkbox"><div class="label-wrapper"><a><label for="LOCATION-level-2-item-0" class="checkbox-label"><div class="checkboxp checkbox-unchecked">&nbsp;</div><span class="valuesdiv"><span class="filter-text">California</span><span class="filter-quantity">(48)</span></span></label></a></div><input id="LOCATION-level-2-item-1" type="checkbox" name="2660420105" title="Maryland" class="filter-checkbox"><div class="label-wrapper"><a><label for="LOCATION-level-2-item-1" class="checkbox-label"><div class="checkboxp checkbox-unchecked">&nbsp;</div><span class="valuesdiv"><span class="filter-text">Maryland</span><span class="filter-quantity">(42)</span></span></label></a></div><input id="LOCATION-level-2-item-2" type="checkbox" name="2360420105" title="Virginia" class="filter-checkbox"><div class="label-wrapper"><a><label for="LOCATION-level-2-item-2" class="checkbox-label"><div class="checkboxp checkbox-unchecked">&nbsp;</div><span class="valuesdiv"><span class="filter-text">Virginia</span><span class="filter-quantity">(41)</span></span></label></a></div>
```

Here's a snippet of the Python script I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver

#Navigate to the main job search page 
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\etherealessence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get(r'https://ngc.taleo.net/careersection/ngc_pro/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en&_ga=2.59113261.1016801192.1577482911-1938918126.1574124672')

#Fill in the "keyword" search input
keyword_element = browser.find_element_by_id('KEYWORD')
keyword_element.send_keys('SQL')

#Find search button and click
submit_button = browser.find_element_by_id('search')
submit_button.click()

#Drop down location field 
location_field = browser.find_element_by_id('LOCATION-link')
location_field.click()
```

Fyi this is my first time using selenium so please be kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on the `checkBox` **California** . You Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `xpath`.

To click on location you need to scroll to element by using `location_once_scrolled_into_view` and then click on that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver.get("https://ngc.taleo.net/careersection/ngc_pro/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en&_ga=2.59113261.1016801192.1577482911-1938918126.1574124672")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"KEYWORD"))).send_keys('SQL')
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"search"))).click()
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@id='LOCATION-link' and text()='Location']")))
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
element.click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[.//span[text()='California']]//div[@class='checkboxp checkbox-unchecked']"))).click()
```

**Browser Snapshot:**

[image]