# In python, how to read a json file as input and get txt file as output? #jupyter notebook

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

I am writing a code to analyze a JSON file. And I want my output as a txt file. The code is as follows..

```
inputFile = "C:\Users\nk\Documents\survey\data.json"
outfile= "C:\Users\nk\Documents\survey\data_summary.txt"
json_file = open(inputFile, 'r', encoding="utf8")
jsondb = json.load(json_file)

fs = open(outFile, 'w')

#some loops in between

fs.flush()
fs.close()
```

after running this code in jupyter notebook, it is showing error like

```
inputFile = "C:\Users\nk\Documents\survey\data.json"              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escap
```

What to do ? and how to write???  I am new to programming.

Comment: How is `typescript` relevant?

Comment: Is the file valid json?

Comment: Oh, and this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37400974/11301900 and  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1347791/11301900.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly this is the problem with your file path. Try to change it in this way:

```
inputFile = r"C:\Users\nk\Documents\survey\data.json"
outfile= r"C:\Users\nk\Documents\survey\data_summary.txt"
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347854/4996863) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the below 3 way to represent you file path correctly:

```
1) inputFile = "C:/Users/nk/Documents/survey/data.json"
   outfile= "C:/Users/nk/Documents/survey/data_summary.txt"

2) inputFile = "C:\\Users\\nk\\Documents\\survey\\data.json"
   outfile= "C:\\Users\\nk\\Documents\\survey\\data_summary.txt"

or as Charnel pointed out:

3) inputFile = r"C:\Users\nk\Documents\survey\data.json"
   outfile= r"C:\Users\nk\Documents\survey\data_summary.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

When typing filenames you used the escape symbol `\` as an ordinary one.
You have three options to avoid this error.

1. Change path delimiters using Unix-style `C:/Users` it works
2. Type every escape symbol twice `C:\\Users`
3. Use special prefix `r` before string `r"C:\Users"`

If you wish to understand more details about the error description you can read this answer

[Unicode Error ”unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes… Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347854/4996863)