# Trouble loading csv file into Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, opencsv

I keep getting errors ie this one:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Dawson\Documents\PMTest.csv")

# ERROR : 
#File "<ipython-input-4-968cc09ba035>", line 2
#pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Dawson\Documents\PMTest.csv")
#               ^
#SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

another error is:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Dawson\Documents\PMTest.csv")
print(df1)
```

same error

Comment: Try: df1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Dawson\Documents\PMTest.csv")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca)