# Discord | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'users.json'

Tags: python, bots, discord

So i'm having trouble setting up my code.
This is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open("users.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

        if message.author.bot:
            return
        if message.channel.is_private:
            return
        else:
            await update_data(users, message.author, message.server)
            number = random.randint(5,10)
            await add_experience(users, message.author, number, message.server)
            await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel, message.server)

        with open("users.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)

async def update_data(users, user, server):
    if not user.id + "-" + server.id in users:
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id] = {}
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["experience"] = 0
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["level"] = 1
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["last_message"] = 0

async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
    if time.time() - users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["last_message"] > 30: 
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["experience"] += exp
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["last_message"] = time.time()
    else:
        return

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
    experience = users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["experience"]
    lvl_start = users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["level"]
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await bot.send_message(channel, f":tada: Congrats {user.mention}, you levelled up to level {lvl_end}!")
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["level"] = lvl_end
```

Typing anything in the server (even it's a letter), gives me this error:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'users.json'`

Even when i try to do another command like "ping", i still get this error

Tried looking it up on the web, but ended up not finding anything.
I would appriciate if you could help me solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try passing the absolute path to users.json Your file user.json is currently not existing.

Comment: So how exactly should i do it?

Comment: pass the path where exactly users.json is placed like (user.json --> C:/Users/Folder/User.json)

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity lol but which line do i put it in?

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: Btw, why are there two file open statements for the same file?

Comment: Can you show your folder layout?

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open("C:/Users/harel/Aero\'s Playground/ArtemiS-IL/users.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

        if message.author.bot:
            return
        if message.channel.is_private:
            return
        else:
            await update_data(users, message.author, message.server)
            number = random.randint(5,10)
            await add_experience(users, message.author, number, message.server)
            await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel, message.server)

        with open("C:/Users/harel/Aero\'s Playground/ArtemiS-IL/users.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)

async def update_data(users, user, server):
    if not user.id + "-" + server.id in users:
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id] = {}
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["experience"] = 0
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["level"] = 1
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["last_message"] = 0

async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
    if time.time() - users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["last_message"] > 30: 
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["experience"] += exp
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["last_message"] = time.time()
    else:
        return

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
    experience = users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["experience"]
    lvl_start = users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["level"]
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await bot.send_message(channel, f":tada: Congrats {user.mention}, you levelled up to level {lvl_end}!")
        users[user.id + "-" + server.id]["level"] = lvl_end
```

Try specifying full path or try moving this Users.json file the folder where this code is running

Comment: -  with open("users.json", "r") as f: C:/Users/Folder/User.json  (Like that?)

Comment: rather than changing path just put users.json inside same folder where python code is running.

Comment: I did. i created a file named "users.json" in the folder where the "bot.py" is sitting, but still nothing

Comment: Same one. "No such file or directory: 'users.json'"

Comment: Can you provide the path where users.json is created.

Comment: C:\Users\harel\Aero's Playground\ArtemiS-IL

Comment: gives me a new error: "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"   (it's regarding the quotes in ("C:/Users/harel/Aero's Playground/ArtemiS-IL/users.json"...)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca

Comment: Now it gives me error "Permission denied: 'C:/Users/harel..."