# python SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape error

Tags: python

i have written a python code in which i have already assigned variable 'emailentry' a string value. what i want to do now is add that string value in the last line of my text file known as 'wattpad.txt'

i have written this code

```
with open("C:\Users\BRS\Desktop\wattpad.txt", 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write(emailentry /n)
```

and getting error

```
File "C:\Users\BRS\Desktop\wattpad acc maker.py", line 41
    with open("C:\Users\BRS\Desktop\wattpad.txt", 'a') as outfile:
              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

pls help
    [Finished in 0.2s]

Comment: It's interpreting the backkslashes as escape characters I think. Change all the \ to \\ and try it again.

Comment: You start a unicode sequence when you do `"\U..."`. Either double your backslashes `"C:\\Users\\BRS\\Desktop\\wattpad.txt"` or use a raw string `r"C:\Users\BRS\Desktop\wattpad.txt"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca)

Answer (score 0):

`\U` is the start of an escape sequence in string litterals, as are [a few others](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) like `\u`, `\n`...

If you want to have litteral backslashes in your string, you can either:

- Escape them:

  `"C:\\Users\\BRS\\Desktop\\wattpad.txt"`
- or better, use a raw string by prefixing the string with `r`:

  `r"C:\Users\BRS\Desktop\wattpad.txt"`
- or use forward slashes, even on Windows:

  `"C:/Users/BRS/Desktop/wattpad.txt"`