# sagetex: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python, windows, command-line, latex, sage

On Windows 10, when trying to execute the following command

```
"C:/Program Files/SageMath 9.1/runtime/bin/bash" -l "C:/Program Files/SageMath 9.1/runtime/opt/sagemath-9.1/sage" -c "os.chdir('C:\Users\Diaa\Desktop\Test'); load('testsagetex.sagetex.sage')"
```

I get the following error

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
> in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

and the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37400974/2849383) can't help me to fix it.

So, what is wrong or missing here knowing that the full the output can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/tp31HHbs).

Comment: "and the answers to this question can't help me to fix it." Yes, they can. They explain the exact problem - it's in the inline Python code `os.chdir('C:\Users\Diaa\Desktop\Test');` that you run with the `-c` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered on the question you linked to.  Try `os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Diaa\Desktop\Test')`