# Trying to unpickle a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to unpickle this data for a while but running into problems

```py
with open ('C:\Users\chhav\OneDrive\Desktop\mnist.pkl','rb') as f:
   mnist_data = pickle.load(f)
```

It gives this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-23-1ef4f2f69776>", line 1
with open ('C:\Users\chhav\OneDrive\Desktop\mnist.pkl','rb') as f:
          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated 
\UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: try `with open ('C:\Users\chhav\OneDrive\Desktop\mnist.pkl','r') as f:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the file path needs to be a raw string to avoid the backslashes. `r'filepath'`

```
with open(r'C:\Users\chhav\OneDrive\Desktop\mnist.pkl','rb') as f:
           mnist_data = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: or you could alternatively use forward slashes, or escape the backslashes with the same effect - using r string is the easiest way for you tho -  fewest changes.

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
with open ('C:/Users/chhav/OneDrive/Desktop/mnist.pkl','rb') as f:
    mnist_data = pickle.load(f)
```

I believe the backslash is interpreted as a protection for special characters

Answer (score 0):

escaping the backslash in file path with one extra backslash could fix this

```
with open ('C:\\Users\\chhav\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\mnist.pkl','rb') as f:
    mnist_data = pickle.load(f)
```