# Error while trying to use pandas to read csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Stock_Data_Set.csv")
df.head()
```

I am trying to read a csv file but when I run this code,I get no error and it stops running.If i remove the r,then it gives a unicode error that is

```
  File "c:\Users\Hp\Desktop\test.py", line 2
    df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Stock_Data_Set.csv")
                     ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX 
escape
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the interpretation of escape characters (any sequence starting with ''). In particular, "\U" introduces a 32-bit unicode character

You should use a raw string to avoid such behaviour (r"xxx")
See https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html, 2.4.1. String and Bytes literals both escape characters and raw strings.

Comment: i have tried double slashes and also tried the back slash method but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Also without raw strings, you can escape \ with another backslash:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\Stock_Data_Set.csv")
```