# Trying to read a pdf in python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

Using `from PyPDF2.pdf import PdfFileReader`

My `temp = open('HW8.pdf', 'rb')` returns an error when run, saying HW8.pdf could not be found even though it's in the same folder as my python code.

Not sure how to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the correct directory; I tried your snippet, and realized that I wasn't in the correct directory. The 'test.pdf' file was on my desktop, and this didn't throw any errors:

```
import os
    
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
os.chdir('/home/asylumax/Desktop')    
temp = open('test.pdf', 'rb')
```

Comment: I implemented ```os.chdir("C:\Users\giodi\invoice-generator")``` and it still returns an error, saying **SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in 
position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape**

Comment: Sounds like the PDF might be damaged or a bit odd.  Create a simple document, save as a PDF, and try that.   This is different than the error you originally got, so that's a start.

Comment: Same thing. Made test.txt and then saved it as a test.pdf. Same error occurred.

Comment: I tried this pdf: https://s1.q4cdn.com/806093406/files/doc_downloads/test.pdf and it worked.  See if you can read it.

Comment: Same problem, same error.

Comment: Check the error; I searched on it, and it could be you need r"...."; see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca  like os.chdir(r"C:\Users\giodi\invoice-generator")

Comment: New error when I put ```os.chdir(r"C:\Users\giodi\invoice-generator")```

**File "C:\Users\giodi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 313, in save self.write_to_fp(f)
 File "C:\Users\giodi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 259, in write_to_fp
prepared_requests = self._prepare_requests()
File "C:\Users\giodi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 201, in _prepare_requests
text_pa
...(ran out of space here)...
AttributeError: 'PageObject' object has no attribute 'strip'**

Comment: Are you doing this from a command line, or from an IDE like Spyder?  Try from a command line.   This should be a straightforward read, and we know the file is good.  So, something about your implementation is off.  Make sure you are in that directory, for sure, with print("pwd:"+os.getcwd())