# unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \uXXXX escape (i am getting this error using a relative path)

Tags: python

so this is my code:

```
csvfile = open("T0\usuarios.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8")

for row in csvfile:

    print(row.split(","))
```

im working on a folder called "T0" where is my python file and also my csv file called "usuarios.csv",  i have tried everything but i kept getting the error that says in the tittle or it says that cant find my  csv file,  im working with a relative path and i cant work with an absolute path but idk what im doing wrong.

Comment: Backslashes are normally interpreted as an escape character inside a string literal; perhaps the most common use is `\n` to produce a newline character.  If you want an *actual backslash* in the string, you either need to double it, or put an `r` in front of the opening quote mark to make it a raw string literal.

Comment: I already tried that :/ and i get this response from vscode " No such file or directory: "

Comment: Well, then your current working directory is apparently not where `T0` is located.

Comment: should try add r before path . ie 
csvfile = open(r"T0\usuarios.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8")
source of answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37402939/9222942

Comment: Where are you executing your script from? From inside the T0-directory or from somewhere else?

Comment: If `T0` is the current working directory, from which you are running python, then you should just be calling `open('usuarios.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')`.  
If you include the 'T0', then its trying to find that subdirectory first, which doesn't exist