# How read a csv file from my computer using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read a CSV file that I have on my computer in a Jupyter Notebook. I using Pandas pd.read_csv(file path)
but I'm getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15328/2333079912.py", line 1
flight_df=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Work\flight.csv')
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: 
truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Here is my code so far:

```
#Calling Libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

flight_df=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Work\flight.csv')
```

Comment: `flight_df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Work\flight.csv')`

Comment: TLDR: google your exact error to find an exact solution... top link for your error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca using backslash `\` in strings will cause problems because it is an escape character. You can use a raw string as above or see reasons here

Answer (score 0):

try `C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Work/flight.csv` or escape `C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop\\Work\\flight.csv`otherwise `\` is interpreted as escape sequence.

Comment: it threw a FileNotFoundError

Comment: which format do you use? does the file exist? `C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Work\flight.csv`

Answer (score 0):

If you change the string to either contain double backslashes `\\` as directory separators or put a `r` in front of it like

```
flight_df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Work\flight.csv')
```

the loading of the file should succeed.

---

As an addition, the error regards the escaping of characters like `\U` in `C:\Users`.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your path as treated as normal string. You can do this to fix your issue:

```
flight_df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Work\flight.csv')
```

Comment: It threw a FileNotFoundError

Comment: Does file exist? Are you sure about the file format?

Comment: it worked thank you, I was missing an s in flights :)