# Not able to run csv file in Python Panda Library

Tags: python, pandas

```
pd.read_csv("C:\Users\thesa\OneDrive\Desktop\Data Sets\datasets-session-16\subs.csv")
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqLJ2.png)

I was trying to read a csv file in jupyter notebook using pandas, but it is not working.

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347854/13855094

Comment: This can help too: 
https://clay-atlas.com/us/blog/2019/10/27/python-english-tutorial-solved-unicodeescape-error-escape-syntaxerror/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/error-unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the string

Here, \U in "C:\Users... starts an eight-character Unicode escape, such as \U00014321.

you can double the backslashes Or prefix the string with r

```
pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\thesa\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Data Sets\\datasets-session-16\\subs.csv")

pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\thesa\OneDrive\Desktop\Data Sets\datasets-session-16\subs.csv")
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted @Animesh, it helps keeping our beloved Stackoverflow of high quality :)

Comment: hi @Animesh, if you are satisfy with answer can you please upvote it so that it will be helpful for other community

Comment: i already did @BigDataLover

Comment: There is a Right click left side of the answer you can click that