# i am getting this error in python when ever i try doing something with the files

Tags: python

```
import os
file = open("C:\Users\tiger\OneDrive\Desktop\demofile.txt","r")
print(file.read())
file.close
```

```
PS C:\Users\tiger> & C:/Users/tiger/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/tiger/test files.py"
  File "c:\Users\tiger\test files.py", line 2
    file = open("C:\Users\tiger\OneDrive\Desktop\demofile.txt","r")
                                             
                 ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
PS C:\Users\tiger>
```

i tried to read the file but it is giving me error

Comment: `\U` has a special meaning in a Python string literal. To avoid that, use `r"C:\Users\tiger\OneDrive\Desktop\demofile.txt"`. Make it a habit to use a raw string like that whenever you're dealing with Windows file paths or regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The  backslash and the letter **t** at word tiger "**\t**iger" in your code at line two is being interpreted as a special function used to represent certain whitespace characters

The quickest solution to solve this is by doubling the backslashes:

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\tiger\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\demofile.txt","r")
print(file.read())
file.close
```

You can find [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/error-unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3) or answer for more details on how to do this

They are other like:-
\n = linefeed (prints the stuff after this on the next line)
\r = carriage return (basically also used for printing stuff on the next line)
\’ = print a single quote ( ‘ ) in your text
\” = print a double quote ( “ ) in your text
\ = print a backslash ( \ ) in your text