# Reading a CSV file with Python code doesnt work

Tags: python, csv

Can anyone tell me why this code is not working?

```
import pandas as pd
​
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\M-Sohrab\Desktop\project\trips.csv')
​
print(df.to_string())
​
```

I am going to read a csv file in Python but the error

**SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape**

shows up!

import pandas as pd
​
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\M-Sohrab\Desktop\project\trips.csv')
​
print(df.to_string())

Comment: What's the actual *full* error? The path isn't escaped so `\Users` will be treated as an escape sequence. Use a raw literal (r'c:\User\...') instead.

Comment: Please format the second code snipped and tell us what's its purpose. Moreover, can you give us some hint on the actual file content? E.g. `cat trips.csv`, a screenshot, whatever

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
​
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\M-Sohrab\Desktop\project\trips.csv')
​
print(df.to_string())
```

I just added an 'r' in front of your string.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/error-unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3) question for more info

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error