# How to read/create a file in a different directory in Python

Tags: python, filepath

I am using the cookie cutter data science project model (https://drivendata.github.io/cookiecutter-data-science/) and would like to open a file in a different directory from my script, read the file, and then create/write a new file to a different directory from my script.  I would like this to work no matter what computer the folder is on (in other words, I can't hard code the absolute path).

I know that some questions already pertain to this issue, but the resulting answers have not worked.  I have mostly been looking at os and pathlib.  Solutions I have attempted include but are not limited to the ones found at these questions: [Open File in Another Directory (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470543/open-file-in-another-directory-python) and [Open file in a relative location in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165749/open-file-in-a-relative-location-in-python).

Below is the relevant parts of the structure of the project:

```
Project
|--data
|    |--external
|    |   --file.txt
|        |--random_pages
|--src
|    |--data
|        --script.py
```

I'd like to use script.py to read file.txt, then create a file in random_pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[2].joinpath("data\\external\\random_pages\\file.txt")
```

Comment: Didn't know about the parents attribute!!  Thanks!!