# Files not being saved in the right directory in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory

I have 2 files:

1. First file `test1.py`:

   ```py
   from dir2.test2 import func2

   def func1():
      with open("test1.txt", "w") as f:
          f.write("some text")

   func1()
   func2()
   ```
2. Second file `test2.py`:

   ```py
   def func2():
       with open("test2.txt", "w") as f:
           f.write("some text")
   ```

And my directory structure looks like this before running `test1.py`:

```
dir1
 |
 - test1.py
 |
 - dir2
    |
    - test2.py
```

After running the `test1.py` the directory structure look like this:

```
dir1
 |
 - test1.txt
 | 
 - test2.txt
 |
 - test1.py
 |
 - dir2
    |
    - test2.py
```

But after running the script I was expecting the directory structure to look like this:

```
dir1
 |
 - test1.txt
 |
 - test1.py
 |
 - dir2
    | 
    - test2.txt
    |
    - test2.py
```

I have tried searching ways to fix this but haven't found any.


So is there anyway to get something like I was expecting after running `test1.py`.

Comment: You need to handle the path yourself. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470543/open-file-in-another-directory-python

Comment: @chandr3sh Since my code is being deployed on a different server on Heroku, I cannot get the full path

Comment: The path is all relative (as per your code) and depends on where you are running the script from. In **"test2.py"**, you may want to specify the path as `./dir2/test2.txt` considering that you are running the script from within `dir1`

Comment: When you first run the script from __main__, it frames you in a specific location - the current working directory. You may be calling test1.py like so: `python /home/dev/dir1/test1.py` or `C:\Users\You\dev\dir1\test1.py`. Python takes in func2 and reads the relative path in the open() call relative to the current working directory (test1.py). This is why it saves the test2.txt file in dir1, not dir2.

Comment: @PeptideWitch So how shall can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative file paths like `"test1.txt"` are relative to the directory you run the script from. Since, you run `test1.py` from the same directory as itself - the relative path is resolved to the same directory as well. So `test1.txt` becomes `/path/to/dir1/test1.txt`

If you ran `test1.py` from within `dir2`, you'd see both text files in `/path/to/dir2/`.

This is how relative paths work in pretty much every language. If you want reliable path building, use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) functions

```py
cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

This will give you an absolute path *to the file you use this on*. So if you use this on `test1.py` - you get `/path/to/dir1`. Now you can use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to build your desired paths

Just for a complete example, to make `test2.txt` inside `dir2` (which is inside `dir1`), assuming that `cwd` line is resolved in `test1.py` (i.e `__file__` points to `test1.py`) you simply do

```py
test2_path = os.path.join(cwd, 'dir2', 'test2.txt')
with open(test2_path, 'w') as f:
    ....
```

And, if `cwd` is resolved in `test2.py` (`__file__` points to test2.py), you do

```py
test2_path = os.path.join(cwd, 'test2.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but what shall my code look like with  `cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` implemented?

Comment: `cwd` stands for *current working directory*, by the way - this is a useful way to think about where code is being called and where relative paths point from

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal As I said, `cwd` is path to the file you call it in. You can now use `os.path.join(cwd, 'dir2')` to get `/path/to/dir1/dir2`, which you can use in `open`

Comment: `os.getcwd()` could also work assuming the code always starts off from test1.py as the main call.

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal I explicitly mentioned you need to join with `dir2` if `__file__` is resolved in `test1.py`, but you put it in `test2.py`. Please read on how `os.path.dirname` works - if you do `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` on `test2.py`, it returns `/path/to/dir1/dir2`. So you should be doing `os.path.join(cwd, 'test2.txt')`